# Restrict the Number of Posts an Author can Publish (over time)?

Tags: posts, plugin-recommendation, author, publish

I'm thinking maybe limit the number of posts a user can make in a given period of time. (Say a user can only publish 1 post per 5 minutes?)
Is there such a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Limit Post Creation Per Day](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-post-creation-per-day/) plugin seems to provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing out there seems to be: http://www.spaw.it/359/wordpress-plugin-limit-post-creation/, but it only sets a single, hard limit.

I think your best bet is to utilize this Wordpress thread with code to limit number of posts for registered users: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-the-number-of-posts-a-user-can-make?replies=18

You would need to change the `$count_posts` var to only count posts made within your time-frame...